# Wordpress: Import files from media library into database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins, phpmyadmin

Well my question is, is it generally possible to write file content (csv or excel) stored in the WP Media library into the database based on a daily or weekly job? If so, are there any plugins that could solve this or should I consider to solve this with coding?

Thank you in advance for any help!

regards Ano

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific plugin anywhere, but simply create your own `mu-plugin` (aka Must-Use-Plugin), mu-plugins are basically plugins that do not need activation (hence always loaded).

Simply create a file at address below:

```
wp-content/mu-plugins/my-plugin.php
```

> And put your code inside.

But beware that mu-plugins run before any other plugin.

See also:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/